# Memory efficient implementation of go map?

Tags: go, maps, heap-memory

My use case is to transfer a group of members (integers) over network, so we employ delta encoding and on the receiving end we decode and put the whole list as a map, 
      map[string]struct{} 
for O(1) complexity for membership check.

The problem I am facing is that the actual size of members is only 15MB for 2 Million integers, but the size of the map in heap is 100+MB. Seems like the actual map implementation of Go is not suitable for large maps. 
Since it is a client side SDK, I do not want to impact the usable memory much, and there can be multiple such groups that need to be kept in memory for long periods of time--around 1 week.

Is there a better alternative DS in Go for this?

```
type void struct{}
func ToMap(v []int64) map[string]void {
 out := map[string]void{}
 for _, i := range v {
   out[strconv.Itoa(int(i))] = void{}
 }
 return out
}
```

Comment: We don't know how you use the map, so it's hard to tell on what / how you could improve your code. One tip you may use is to create a map with capacity provided, if you know how many elements you need to store in it. For that, you may use `make(map[string]struct{}, capacity)`.

Comment: added the code implementation of how maps is being constructedv

Comment: Is there a reason why a `string` is used for the keys?

Comment: "the size of the map in heap is 100+MB" how did you measure this. Are you sure this number is correct? And why on earth are you storing the ints in their string representations? **Don't** **do** **that**.

Comment: the groups could be comprised on integers or strings, hence decided to keep a map of strings for the client sdk to use. So, it calls group.IsMember(<string>) , which is O(1) operation for now.

Comment: The size of the `string` representation of an `int64` may be 4 times bigger than the size of `int64` itself. If you do need memory optimized solution, don't convert them to `string`. If you do need to handle both integers and strings, consider using 2 maps, one with `int64` keys and one with `string` keys. And in your example code, you may create the map with capacity, like: `out := make(map[int64]void{}, len(v))`

Comment: Used the runtime stats to calculate the heap usage. Found the actual size of the members by adding up the bytes of each member. Members size = 15MB, map size = 108 MB

Comment: As others pointed out, avoid string representations for integers. Use `int` or, if possible, `(u)int32`. If the map is still too big, consider a sorted slice and use [sort.SearchInts](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#SearchInts) (or SearchStrings if you really can't avoid that) for O(log n) in the worst case.

Comment: If you want to keep strings and ints in the same map than _please_ use at least an efficient string representation and not base10!! Also: Heap usage is a good indicator of the memory consumption of the whole program but not really suitable to measure the memory usage of a map. Redesign!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a more memory efficient form of the map:

```
type void struct{}

func ToMap(v []int64) map[int64]void {
    m := make(map[int64]void, len(v))
    for _, i := range v {
        m[i] = void{}
    }
    return m
}
```

Go maps are optimized for integer keys. Optimize the map allocation by giving the exact map size as a hint.

A `string` has an implicit pointer which would make the garbage collector (gc) follow the pointer every time it scans.

---

Here is a Go benchmark for 2 million pseudorandom integers:

```
package main

import (
    "math/rand"
    "strconv"
    "testing"
)

type void struct{}

func ToMap1(v []int64) map[string]void {
    out := map[string]void{}
    for _, i := range v {
        out[strconv.Itoa(int(i))] = void{}
    }
    return out
}

func ToMap2(v []int64) map[int64]void {
    m := make(map[int64]void, len(v))
    for _, i := range v {
        m[i] = void{}
    }
    return m
}

var benchmarkV = func() []int64 {
    v := make([]int64, 2000000)
    for i := range v {
        v[i] = rand.Int63()
    }
    return v
}()

func BenchmarkToMap1(b *testing.B) {
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        ToMap1(benchmarkV)
    }
}

func BenchmarkToMap2(b *testing.B) {
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        ToMap2(benchmarkV)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ go test tomap_test.go -bench=.
BenchmarkToMap1-4     2  973358894 ns/op    235475280 B/op    2076779 allocs/op
BenchmarkToMap2-4    10  188489170 ns/op     44852584 B/op         23 allocs/op
$
```

Comment: This is not completely accurate. For the test that uses int64 keys you are initialising the map with an initial capacity, whereas you are not doing it for the string case. The end numbers of course still show that using int64 keys is faster, but the difference is not so abysmal.